# Can you break a string down into an array of characters in C?

Tags: c

How do I break down a string into an array of characters, so that I can individually analyze and work with each letter within the string?

Example type code, whereas i would be each letter...

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("what is the string?: ");
    string s = GetString();
    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    printf("s[i]");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What is `GetString()` ? Did you mean `gets()` ? And if yes, then C string already *is* an array of char. If `s` is a C string, you can use `s[0]` up to `s[strlen(s) - 1]`.

Comment: `string` in C? Can you show us the definition of `string`?

Comment: with the caveat "never ever *EVER* use 'gets0"" ;)

Comment: In C++, "string" is a standard library "class".  In C, you only have "char[]" arrays.

Comment: There is no string. There are only characters.

Comment: From this code sample I'd hazard you are actually using C++.

Comment: Here's something that I refer to about every 2 minutes when I code in C,  http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/  Also, check out http://c-faq.com/  Good luck with programming!

Answer (score 2):

A string *is* an array of characters (with an extra "\0" being the last element in the array).

```
#define MAXLEN 80

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[MAXLEN];
    printf("what is the string?: ");
    fgets (buf, MAXLEN, stdin);
    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(buff); i++)
      printf("buff[%d]: %c\n", i, buf[i]);
    return(0);
}
```

===== One more example =====

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  char string[] = "ABC";

  for (i=0; i < strlen (string); i++) {
    printf ("%c\n", string[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
A
B
C
```

Comment: i appreciate the response, but am too new at programming to understand the above..

Comment: Q: What don't you understand?  I was only saying that a "string" (which I've renamed "buf", short for "buffer") is simply an array of characters.  If you want to access a character, use "buf[i]".  If you want to printf a character, use "%c" in your format string.

Answer (score 0):

In c, a string **is** an array of characters.

Comment: so how in the above example would i evaluate (or even just print) each letter individually?
I am using a class library from a course i am taking that allows for strings and the GetString(); input function...

Answer (score 0):

A string is already an array of characters and can be treated that way already. Anything you can do with an array you can do with a string so it is best to keep it simple and just use the array. Unless you have some reason that you haven't mentioned, but I can't think of one.

Comment: so how in the above example would i evaluate (or even just print) each letter individually?
I am using a class library from a course i am taking that allows for strings and the GetString(); input function...

Comment: In my example, I printed each letter individually with `printf ("%c", buf[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char* string;

//input string from console stdin
string GetString(){
    char buff[1024];
    int len;
    fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin);
    len = strlen(buff);
    if(buff[len-1] == '\n')
        buff[len-1]='\0';
    return strdup(buff);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("what is the string?: ");
    string s = GetString();
    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(s); i++)
        printf("s[%d]:%c\n", i, s[i]);

    char ca[strlen(s)+1];
    for(int i = 0; i<=strlen(s); i++)
        ca[i]=s[i];

    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(s); i++)
        printf("ca[%d]:%c\n", i, ca[i]);
    free(s);
    return(0);
}
/*
what is the string?: test
s[0]:t
s[1]:e
s[2]:s
s[3]:t
ca[0]:t
ca[1]:e
ca[2]:s
ca[3]:t
*/
```